# Increase speed for loop operation with condition check and create object within in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

My objective is to check the condition for a cell value in a dataframe and store the return value in a cell of a new variable. I have used the code below in R to achieve the same. However, the process is very slow and takes hours to get final results. How can I modify the code below to increase processing speed?

In the code below
k : Row number
DF3: Dataframe

```
R1 <- seq(1, 2296800, 1)
for (k in seq_along(R1)){
  if(DF3[k,6]>0){
    DF3$Slack=DF3[k,6]
  } else {
    DF3$Slack=0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
DF3$Slack <- ifelse(DF3[[6]] > 0, DF3[[6]], 0)
```

Or better/faster option would be `pmax`

```
DF3$Slack <- pmax(DF3[[6]], 0)
```